# possible to log in to an ADFS environment with only a UPN

Tags: ldap, office365, saml-2.0, adfs2.0

We have an application that checks against active directory for valid UN/PW combinations with a simple LDAP query.  That query simply responds with a message of yes or now to validate the user.  Unfortunatley we have no control over this application so can't make it a claims aware applicaiton which would provide AD access to the user.

Is there a way with SAML or something to log a user in to AD / ADFS with only their email address (UPN) so that we can then provide them access to other services on our domain?

Ultimately, we are going to use the token to SSO the users to an Office365 implementation that we have.

Answer (score 0):

ADFS will authenticate against AD via several methods, one of them being username/password. You don't need your homegrown application.